# Flutter double-tap functionality on the system keypad to enhance accessibility for visually impaired individuals

Tags: flutter, accessibility

I have a Flutter text field with accessibility enabled. When the user starts typing, it should speak after a double-tap on the keypad, and text should be entered afterward. This functionality was working for a custom keypad with buttons, but how can we achieve it for the default Android keypad?

```
 TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              hintText: 'Enter a search term',
            ),
          ),
```